Characterizations of the Jacobson Radical
I am currently studying the concept of the Jacobson radical of a ring, and have gotten confused about whether or not certain conditions are equivalent characterizations of the radical. Suppose that $\Lambda$ is a unital, not necessarily commutative, ring. I have seen that the following are equivalent for an element $x \in \Lambda$:

$x$ is in $J(\Lambda)$, the Jacobson radical of $\Lambda$.

$1 - yx$ has a left inverse for all $y \in \Lambda$.

$1 - yxy'$ has a two-sided inverse for all $y, y' \in \Lambda$.


From (3), we see that $J(\Lambda) = J(\Lambda^{op}$), and then applying (2) to $J(\Lambda^{op})$ gives us a fourth equivalent condition.

$1 - xy$ has a right inverse for all $y \in \Lambda$.

This prompted me to wonder if the following are also equivalent conditions for being in $J(\Lambda)$.

$1 - xy$ has a left inverse for all $y \in \Lambda$.

$1 - yx$ has a right inverse for all $y \in \Lambda$.


Certainly, 3 implies 5 and 6, but is the other direction true as well? I have not seen either 5 or 6 mentioned anywhere, so I am suspecting that it is not true, but I am having trouble coming up with a counterexample.
Thank you in advance for any help.

Hi there, what is the definition of Jacobson Radical you are using define $J(\Lambda)$? whist you have given lots of equivalent definitions you haven given your baseline one. I did study this at one point and my memory tells me that 5 <=> 6 <=> 3 and the proof is not too complicated (though there is a small chance I am misremembering) I could perhaps dig up a proof In a text book shortly.

@user2628206 I am taking my definition of $J(\Lambda)$ to be condition 2.

Exercise 1.6 in T.Y.Lam's "A first course in Noncommutative rings" shows that "$1-ba$ is left invertible implies $1-ab$ is left invertible". In fact, $a(1-xy) = 1$ implies $(1+yax)(1-yx) = 1 + ya(1-xy)x-yx = 1$. See also here and the link on that page.

Thanks Amatur Algebraist - I went spelunking into that book but missed that key proof and had all but given up
